# Query Builder Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

How to make query builder laravel, with table
following:

I have a table
Radusergroup with column:

1. id
2. username
3. groupname
4. priority
5. status
6. reseller_id

I want to select
1. display reseller_id with all data having reseller_id and grouped by reseller_id

example:

```
reseller_id with ID Res_1 displaying username_1,username_2 , and count from amount username
reseller_id with ID Res_2 displayinh username_3, username_4, and count from amount username
```

can any help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make query in laravel like:

```
                      DB::table('Radusergroup ')->select('id','username','groupname','priority','status','reseller_id')
                     ->groupBy('reseller_id')
                     ->get();
```

Comment: Can't , that query displaying 2 record, i want all record... i have some data

Comment: Could you plz provide the reseller table details ?

Comment: If you have only 2 types of reseller_id, then if you use group by, you always get 2 records only. Are you sure, you want grouped by reseller_id?